# Swift Completion Handlers in GameKit

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, gamekit

How can I implement the following in Swift?

```
func findMatchForRequest(_ request: GKMatchRequest!,
   withCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((GKMatch!,
                                  NSError!) -> Void)!)
```

When I tried

```
var request = GKMatchRequest();
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 4;    
GKMatchmaker.sharedMatchmaker().findMatchForRequest(request, withCompletionHandler: { (match : GKMatch!, error: NSError!) -> Void in {

                }
            })
```

it gives a "can not convert the expression type" compilation error. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. You just have an unnecessary set of braces in your completion handler. Here's the correct version:

```
GKMatchmaker.sharedMatchmaker().findMatchForRequest(
    request,
    withCompletionHandler: {(match : GKMatch!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        NSLog("This works")
})
```

EDIT: I meant braces!

Comment: Those aren't parentheses -- they're braces.

Answer (score 1):

FYI you could use trailing closure:

```
GKMatchmaker.sharedMatchmaker().findMatchForRequest(request) {
match, error in
        println("This works")
}
```

Comment: `-> Void` is redundant

Comment: True, as type definitions (and even inputs declarations). I edited my answer, ty for noticing it.